# Spark Structured Streaming : Save Events from Kafka in Database and Aggregate same events and send alerts

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I wanted to know how can I accomplish saving events (events are in JSON format and will be saved in the same format ) from kafka and apply aggregation on the same dataset and raise alarm/alert if it meets certain criteria .
It looks like there will be two queries where first one will be saving event data in the datasbase using forEachBatch and second one which will be getting aggregate data and raise alert based on forEach loop .
My questions :

1. Can I run both queries simultaneously and get same data for saving it and post that apply aggregation ?
2. I am assuming I have to run two queries for it where first one saves it and second one which I use for aggregation and raise alarm/alerts.

Please advise. I am a beginner in Spark so please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks
Xslguy

Comment: One `readStream` is enough for both operations. You can run both queries at the same time.  You need one `writeStream` to ingest into the database using `foreach/foreachbatch` implementation. and for aggregation a simple steaming query.

Comment: Thanks Vikram , could you elaborate a little more by providing very high level  code may be a line or two that how can I use the same write stream for both the operations as both queries are different , my thought process is that we have to use two write stream . (which may not be correct ) . Please elaborate a bit more.